# Convert to DateTime object

Tags: c#, datetime

I have c# program that among other things should be able to parse a string that looks like this:

2011-09-20_104627

To a valid DateTime object.

Can anyone help me with the code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [DateTime.TryParseExact()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h9b85w22.aspx)

```
string myDateTimeString = "2011-09-20_104627";
DateTime myDateTimeObject;
DateTime.TryParseExact(myDateTimeString,
                       "yyyy-MM-dd_HHmmss",
                       CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                       DateTimeStyles.None,
                       out myDateTimeObject);
```

**Note:** "HH" == 24-hour format. "hh" == 12-hour format.

Comment: Just tested: `hh` fails for hours>=12

Comment: @CodeInChaos, fixed, sorry. Should be `HH` not `hh`

Answer (score 4):

`DateTime.ParseExact` looks like a good guess.

In your case `DateTime.ParseExact("2011-09-20_104627","yyyy-MM-dd_HHmmss",System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` works.

Answer (score 3):

Untested, off the cuff...

```
DateTime dt;
// HH for 24-hour clock; hh for 12-hour clock
if (DateTime.TryParseExact("yyyy-MM-dd_HHmmss", out dt)) 
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use DateTime.ParseExact with a custom format rule.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

I don't know what 014627 is in your example, but it would start with

```
yyyy-MM-dd_
```